# Multiple regex search in Python script.

Tags: python, regex

Am new to all this.

I want to batch together several regexes in a single Python script.

Each regex work fine when regex searching through a text file in Notepad++.

However, when combined it's not working. Not working means valid hit found with Notepad++ search is not returned by my Python script.

Running Python 3.7.

Thanks in advance.

```
# import Python's regular expression module
import re

# file to check; assumes target file is in the same dir as Python script
target = 'test target file.txt'  

# declare series of regexes; see top for explanation of each
regexes = [re.compile('^\+'),
       re.compile('^[\s+][A-Z]'),
       re.compile('\d$\r\n[cm,%,\),l,ml,hPa,°,bar,psi,V,W,]'),
       re.compile('^[1-9]{1,2}\.(.*)\r\n^\r\n^[1-9]{1,2}\.(.*)'),
       re.compile('FN-'),
       re.compile('gfx'),
       re.compile('tbl'),
       re.compile('Missing link'),
       ]

# open target file, search for matches, output to screen
with open(target) as fp:  
   for line in target:
    for cnt, line in enumerate(fp):
      if any(regex.match(line) for regex in regexes):
        print("Line {}: {}".format(cnt, line))
```

Comment: Read the docs about the flags that `re.compile` can take.

Comment: `regex.match` only searches at the start of the string. Use `regex.search`.